# Insert record to database from a server/client GUI java

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, server, client

Hi i am struggling to get my database to receive a username and ip address from a client instance connecting to a server.

It is a bidding system that initially just lets multiple individual instances of the client bid on 2 items, now I need to add the name (user prompted to enter upon loading client instance) and their ip address to my database.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null; //null pointer exception fix

        Statement statement = null;
        String inserSql = null;
        Connection sqlLink = null;
        final int PORT = 1239;
        Socket client = null;
        ClientHandler handler = null;
        Scanner getTime;

        try {
            /**
             * This piece of code has errors or you maybe did the error 
             * when copy/paste your code.
             * Fixed the DriverManager connection code
             */
            sqlLink = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "correct info already here);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("* Cannot connect to database! *");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            System.out.println("Unable to set up port!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("\nUp and running\n");
        String currentTime = null;
        getTime = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nSet time for Ball");
        currentTime = getTime.nextLine();
        Items BallItem = new Items("Ball", currentTime, "Ball");

        System.out.println("\nSet time for Plate");
        currentTime = getTime.nextLine();
        Items PlateItem = new Items("Plate", currentTime, "Plate");

        Bidder bidder = new Bidder(null);

        BallItem.start();
        PlateItem.start();

        Users user = new Users(BallItem, PlateItem);
        ArrayList<ClientHandler> userList =
                new ArrayList<ClientHandler>();
        //add new array for the clients details as stated
        ArrayList<String> bidders = new ArrayList<String>();

        do {
            client = serverSocket.accept();//
            System.out.println("Enter username ");//
            //takes in bidders name (1.1 and 2.1)

            bidders.add(getTime.nextLine());
            bidders.add(client.getInetAddress().toString());
            //takes in next bidder's ip address to string like in tips (2.2)

            Bidder userBidding = new Bidder(bidders);

            System.out.println("\nUser" + (user.getUsers() + 1));
            user.addUsers(userList, client, handler);
            System.out.println(userBidding.returnUsers());

            bidder.insert(statement, statement);

        }
        while (true);
    }
}

class Items extends Thread {
    private String name, description, timeUp, userBidding = "";
    private boolean newBid = true;
    private double topBid = 0;
    private Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();

    private int date = start.get(Calendar.DATE);  //gets the dates
    private int month = start.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    private int year = start.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    private Calendar deadline = Calendar.getInstance();
    //time file supplied to help etc
    private Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    public Items(String newName, String newTimeString,
                 String newDescription) throws IOException {
        String timeString, hourString, minString;

        name = newName;
        description = newDescription;
        timeUp = newTimeString;
        timeString = newTimeString;

        hourString = timeString.substring(0, 2);
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourString);
        minString = timeString.substring(3, 5);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(minString);

        deadline.set(year, month, date, hour, minute, 0);      //setting time
    }

    public void run() {
        while (now.before(deadline)) {
            System.out.println(name + " " + getDateTime(now));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000); //increased to check server notifications easier
            } catch (InterruptedException intEx) {
            }
            now = Calendar.getInstance();
        }
        System.out.println("\nDeadline! Times up!");
        newBid = false;
    }

    class Bidder {

        private static ArrayList<String> users;
        private static Users user = new Users(null, null);

        public Bidder(ArrayList<String> newUserList) {
            users = newUserList;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> returnUsers()//return users as in question
        {
            return users;
        }

        public static String returnIP()//return ip as in question
        {
            return users.get(user.getUsers() + 1);
        }

        static void insert(Statement insert, Statement statement) {
            Users user = new Users(null, null);
            try {

                String insertSql = "INSERT INTO Usernames(id, Name, ipAddress) VALUES (1"
                        + users.get(user.getUsers()) + "," + returnIP() + ")";

                System.out.println(users.get(user.getUsers()));
                statement.executeUpdate(insertSql);
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
                System.out.println("* Cannot execute insert! *");
                sqlEx.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        //remove user as stated in question
        public synchronized void RemoveUser(Socket client, int clientUser) {
            int index = 0;
            for (final String newString : users) {
                if (users.indexOf(user.getUsers()) == clientUser) {
                    try {
                        client.close();
                        Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();
                        users.remove(index);
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Try to leave again!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
    }


    class Users {
        private ArrayList<ClientHandler> userList;
        private Items Ball;
        private Items Plate;

        public Users(Items newItem1, Items newItem2) {
            Ball = newItem1;
            Plate = newItem2;
            userList = null;
        }


        public synchronized int getUsers() {
            int totalUsers = 0;
            if (userList != null)
                for (ClientHandler handler : userList)
                    totalUsers++;
            return totalUsers;
        }
    }// <-- miss this close brace
```

Comment: Where did you try it? Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: I tried it within the last 15 minutes trying different methods but i cannot get it to work. I can insert rows using hard coded values i can do it via user entering each time then executing the code but doing this method confuses me.
I suppose i could do it by when i enter the name it goes to a variable and then the variable goes into insert statement?

Comment: fixed some piece of code with critical errors and improved the block code style